# Mixed model instead of RM anova?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling, repeated-measures

I have data points collected at 4 time points for $N$ subjects. I need to understand if there is a difference in mean readings at these 4 time points, and also if age and gender influence these mean values. I should note that the mean subject boxplot is a U curve across time.

My initial approach was to use repeated measures ANCOVA, but then I decided to incorporate the random variations in the subjects as random slope model, thus I am now using mixed models.

My model would be: `y  ~ gender * age * Time`, where `Time = 1, 2, 3` and 4, `age` is continuous. I have tried using `lme` (`nlme`) and `lmer` (lme4) for this analysis, but both fail for different reasons.

`lme` model: `m1 = lme(y ~ gender * age * Time, random = Time|subject, data=dat)`. Here `Time` is factor. The `lme` package fails with convergence error if I treat time as continuous.

`lmer` model: `m2 = lmer(y ~ gender * age * Time + (Time|subject), data = dat)`, here Time in continuous. The lme4 package fails with an error: number of observations <= number of random effects.

My initial assumption was both fit a line but that does not seem to be the case. When I fit the model as m2 (lmer), and get the fitted values, the output is a straight line. While, m1 (lme) returns a curve. I am not sure I understand what lme does? If I have not used a polynomial term, how is it giving me a U curve?

Finally, I was wondering if I look at this problem from the regression point of view, I need a curve fit, but if I think of just checking for difference in mean, i.e. using anova on the models, I’m not so sure I need a non-linear model. I think my confusion stems from the fact if I have a U curve at 4 time points, and if I just want to know if there is change in mean readings at these 4 time points, should I use linear lme or lme with non-linear predictors? Also, why does m1 return a curve and not a fitted line?

**[Edit]** Code example with sample data:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
library(lmerTest)

# random data set, with different means set at different time points
set.seed(3114)
df <- data.frame('subject'=paste0('s',c(1:40)))
dat <- data.frame(t1 = runif(40, min=800, max=1000),
                  t2 = runif(40, min=400, max=600),
                  t3 = runif(40, min=400, max=600),
                  t4 = runif(40, min=900, max=1000))
dat <- cbind(df, dat)
dat <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.vars = c('subject'))
dat <- dat %>% select(subject, Time = variable, y=value) %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub('t','', Time),
         Time = factor(Time),
         Time1 = as.numeric(Time))
# nlme model, time is a factor
m1 = nlme::lme(y ~ Time, random = ~Time|subject, data=dat)
# lmer model, time is continuous
# also deliberately fitted with a line for testing
m2 = lmerTest::lmer(y ~ Time1 + (Time1|subject), data = dat)
dat$fitted_m1 <- fitted(m1)
dat$fitted_m2 <- fitted(m2)

# pick a random subject to plot
# black line - original data
# red line - nlme model output
# blue line is - lmer model output
# I assumed that nlme does the same thing as lmer, but can't seem to intrepret the 
# non-linearity in the plots
ggplot(dat[dat$subject=='s5',]) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y, x=Time), color = 'black') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=y, x=Time, group = 1), color='black') +
  geom_point(aes(y=fitted_m1, x=Time), color = 'red') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=fitted_m1, x=Time, group = 1), color='red') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=fitted_m2, x=Time), color = 'blue') +
  geom_line(aes(y=fitted_m2, x=Time, group = 1), color = 'blue') + 
  ylab('fitted values')
```

**Plot:**
[image: Plot demonstrating the curve]

Comment: Can you add the plot you are referring to? Also, what if you fit the `lmer` model with the random effect specified as `(1|subject)`?

Comment: Can you tell us the context? What are you measuring? And can you share (a link to) the data?

Comment: Thank you, added sample data and plot.

Comment: Are all the four measurements at the same time or they are distributed across the time domain (and just happen to be 4 for each individual)?

Comment: Also can you please add all the libraries you are using in the start of your script?

Comment: Do the code and plot help Erik Ruzek and @kjetilbhalvorsen? Erik: I am using Time|subject, which should also include 1|subject.

usεr11852 could you please elaborate on the measurement distribution across time domain question?